# Find $a\in(2,\infty)$ if $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^8-x^2}{x^{12}+ax^6+1}dx=-\frac{\pi}{24}$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find $a\in(2,\infty)$ if $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^8-x^2}{x^{12}+ax^6+1}dx=-\frac{\pi}{24}$. To this I thought to break the integral in two smaller ones and for the first use the sustitution $x^6=t$ and for the second $x^3=t$. The $\pi$ makes me think I have to come closer to an integral that yields $ arctan$.  However, they get pretty tangled. Any help?

Answer (score 7):

Make substitution $u=x^3$;
$$\begin{align*}
I(a) &=\frac13\int_0^1 \frac{u^2-1}{u^4+au^2+1}du
\\&=\frac 13 \int_0^1 \frac{1-\frac1{u^2}}{u^2+a+\frac1{u^2}}du.
\end{align*}$$ Further make $v=u+\frac 1 u$ to obtain
$$\begin{align*}
I(a) &=-\frac13\int_{2}^\infty \frac{1}{v^2+a-2}dv
\\&=-\frac1{3\sqrt{a-2}}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{v}{\sqrt{a-2}}\right)\right]^\infty_{2}
\\&=-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{a-2}}\left(\frac\pi 2-\arctan\left(\frac2{\sqrt{a-2}}\right)\right).
\end{align*}$$ We can see $a=6$ solves the equation. It can be noted that this is the only solution because 
$
\displaystyle I(a)=-\frac13\int_{2}^\infty \frac{1}{v^2+a-2}dv
$ is strictly increasing in $a>2$.

Comment: How is this any different from att epl's solution?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
First substitute $x^3=t$  Then you should get a quadratic  divided by a biquadratic polynomial times $\dfrac{1}{3}.$Then divide the expression by $t^2$ and substitute $w=t+\dfrac{1}{t}$ .This should simplify your integral as the integral of derivative of arctan(something) $\times$  $\dfrac{1}{3a-6}$ where the integral is from $\infty \to 2$ ....Reverse the limits and simplify.

Comment: (Also see @below)

Answer (score 0):

*Partial answer:*

You should instead use $t = x^3, dt = 3x^2 \ dx$:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^8-x^2}{t^4+at^2+1} \frac{dt}{3x^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{t^2-1}{t^4+at^2+1} dt$$